# Page Tables Causing Crash

Tags: assembly

I am trying to boot a fork of Apple’s XNU kernel ([sources available here](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel)) on VirtualBox 4.3.6. VirtualBox aborts execution of the VM as soon as XNU takes control from the booter, due to a fatal hardware exception within the VM.

Investigation of the VirtualBox logs ([available here](https://gist.github.com/wjk/61968386fda8b5475da0)) reveals the cause of the crash as corruption of the PDPTE. I have traced the crash to [these source lines](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/x86_64/start.s#L181-L189) (please excuse the poor syntax coloring). The lines load the PDPTE from [their definitions](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/x86_64/boot_pt.c#L46-L60). I cannot see a problem in the data loaded. Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the problem is that VirtualBox itself crashed.

In this case, the code running inside the virtual machine at the time may be perfectly correct (e.g. perfectly correct XNU code that happens to trigger a bug in VirtualBox's code).

If the code running inside the virtual machine crashed, then you'd just end up running exception handler/s inside the virtual machine, and VirtualBox itself would continue running.

Of course it's possible for both to happen at the same time. For example, a bug in XNU's code that triggers a bug in VirtualBox's code. For this reason, I'd strongly recommend trying XNU inside a different emulator (to determine if the problem is XNU or VirtualBox or both).

Comment: I tried booting the same disk image in QEMU, and QEMU simply ran the same boot sequence over and over and over. My guess is that QEMU is experiencing the same problem that VirtualBox had; QEMU just doesn’t report it as well.